# How to iterate through matrix and change floats through calculation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix

I have the following list:

```py
N_division_n = [0.0, 1.0, 0.4150374992788437]
```

And I have the following matrix:

```py
sample_collection =
[['', 'test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt', 'test4.txt'], 
['apple', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
['banana', 1;0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
['lemon', 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0]]
```

I would like to multiply all values in the matrix rows with the corresponding value in the earlier list. Like this: `apple values * 0.0, banana values * 1.0, lemon values * 0.4150374992788437`.

I have tried constructing the following but it does not want to iterate through the floats and I am not sure how to fix it.

```py
def tf_df_calculation(sample_collection):
    for a in range(1,len(sample_collection)):
        tf_df_list = [item[a] for item in N_division_n]
        value_a = 0
        for i in tf_df_list:
            if type(i) is float:
                value_a = i * N_division_n
                sample_collection.append(value_a)

tf_df_calculation(sample_collection)
```

expected output:

```
[['', 'test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt', 'test4.txt'], 
['apple',  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
['banana',  1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
['lemon',  0.41503749927884376, 0.0, 0.8300749985576875, 0.41503749927884376]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple function works but it uses two for loops. Anyway, it is not an issue if your matrices are small.

```
N_division_n = [0.0, 1.0, 0.4150374992788437]

sample_collection = [['', 'test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt', 'test4.txt'], 
['apple', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
['banana', 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
['lemon', 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0]]

def tf_df_calculation(sample_collection):
    for a in range(1,len(sample_collection)):
        for b in range(1,len(sample_collection[a])):
            sample_collection[a][b] *= N_division_n[a-1]

tf_df_calculation(sample_collection)

print(sample_collection)
```

Output

```
[['', 'test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt', 'test4.txt'], ['apple', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], ['banana', 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], ['lemon', 0.4150374992788437, 0.0, 0.8300749985576874, 0.4150374992788437]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
N_division_n = [0.0, 1.0, 0.4150374992788437]

sample_collection =[['', 'test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt', 'test4.txt'], ['apple', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], ['banana', 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], ['lemon', 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0]]

results = [sample_collection[0]]
count = 0
for sample in sample_collection[1::]:
    calculated_line = [sample[0]] + [x*N_division_n[count] for x in sample[1::]]
    results.append(calculated_line)
    count += 1
```

Output:

```
[['', 'test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt', 'test4.txt'], ['apple', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], ['banana', 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], ['lemon', 0.4150374992788437, 0.0, 0.8300749985576874, 0.4150374992788437]]
```

Comment: You can use `enumerate` on your loop to avoid using a counter. Ex: `for i, sample in enumerate(sample_collection[1::])`. Then use `i` instead of `counter`, it will be automatically incremented.